# Prepend a string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following to prepend my `asset/img` paths with a new string, in this case `my-path`.

```
str.replace(/=('|")(\/?assets\/img)/g, "my-path$&");
```

Unfortunately it's prepending before the `=` so I get something like:

```
<img srcmypath="/assets/img/image.jpg">
```

How can I get it to prepend after the `="` So I get:

```
<img src="mypath/assets/img/image.jpg">
```

Comment: why don't you simple use str.replace("assets/img", "my-path$&"); .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groups to reference the stuff you want after replacing. Groups are defined with parentheses.

```
str.replace(/(=['"])(\/?assets\/img)/g, '$1mypath$2')
              ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^      ^^- text of 2nd group
              1st     2nd group          |       
              group                      text of first group
```

will result in

`<img src="mypath/assets/img/image.jpg">`

Comment: It works fine with a leading slash. the slash will be also in the group2 if not ignored.

Answer (score 2):

First I would capture `/assets` as follows:

```
(\/assets)
```

And then I would apply the following substitution:

```
my-path$1
```

So if my original sentence was:

```
<img src="/assets/img/image.jpg">
```

I would get something like:

```
<img src="my-path/assets/img/image.jpg">
```

This is the code regex101 generated for my regular expression:

```
const regex = /(\/assets)/g;
const str = `<img src="/assets/img/image.jpg">`;
const subst = `my-path\$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

UPDATE: If you only want to match those lines that also contain src then you could use the following matching pattern:

```
(src=")(\/assets)
```

And this how you would replace it:

```
$1my-path$2
```

Comment: What if I had other parts of the document referring to /assets, then this would also be replaced, Im trying to target src paths only.

Answer (score 0):

You could begin by trying sth. like

```
(img src=")(\/?)(assets\/img\/)(.*?)(")
```

and then use the capturing groups for your replacements as shown [in this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/VQUuMJ/2)

```js
var testCases = [
 '<img src="assets/img/image.jpg">',
 '<img src="/assets/img/image.jpg">'
]

for(var i=0; i<testCases.length; i++)
{
 console.log(testCases[i].replace(/(img src=")(\/?)(assets\/img\/)(.*?)(")/g, "$1mypath/$3$4$5"));
}
```